# Push multiple Object into array and assigning to jqxGrid

Tags: javascript, arrays, jqxgrid

I have this two elements

```
var col = {
    text: 'Foo',
    datafield: 'John',
    width: 120,
    cellsalign: 'right',
    cellsformat: 'c2'

};
var cols = {
    text: 'Bar',
    datafield: 'Doe',
    width: 120,
    cellsalign: 'right',
    cellsformat: 'c2'

};
```

I am trying to push this to an array like so

```
var foobar= [];
foobar.push(col,cols);
```

I am pretty sure that above syntax is correct and the correct way to do it. Please do correct me if I am wrong.

And now when I put this inside the initialization of `jqxGrid` like so

```
 $("#module_management_table").jqxGrid(
    {
        width: 'calc(100% - 20%)',
        source: dataAdapter,
        columnsresize: true,
        columns: [colu]
    });
```

I give me this error

> cannot read property 'length' of null

But for some weird reason when I just add one element `col` to the columns array it works fine

```
columns: [col]
```

Comment: Where exactly is `length` being called? And not sure about `jqxGrid` syntax, but it might be just `columns: foobar`, since it's already an array, you don't have to put it inside another array, or so I assume.

Comment: `columns: [col, cols]` - no need for 2 extra steps

Comment: Thanks you both for the help. Solved it. I was `columns: foobar`.